# Converting Kubernetes resource type to primitive data types

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

```golang
func GetK8sDeploymentMetadata(clustername string, namespace string)([]v1.Deployment, error) {
    deploymentMetadata, err:=clientset[clustername].AppsV1().Deployments(namespace).List(v1.ListOptions{})
    return deploymentMetadata.Items , err  
}
```

I have a function which returns metadata of deployment of type `[]v1.Deployment` .My question is how can i convert `[]v1.Deployment` to `[]string`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Serialize `Deployment` object?

Comment: no i just want to convert deployment object to string array

Comment: Can you provide an example of result that you want to get?

Comment: do you know how deployment.Items looks like?

Comment: my array also should look like that and work like that only .work like that in the sense, i should be able to range over that array and get image name , deployment name and everything required

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/63b8484e576699c2f714dd6319c827a568a95090/apps/v1/types.go#L254) is definition of deployment struct, as you can see it contains other structs as it''s fields. It doesn't have an Items field. If you can't provide example of what you trying to do, i can't help you.

Comment: additionally it'll be good to present a result you already have